# How to write MifareClassic with Custom Key

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

I need to find a solution to write Mifare Classic 1 K Tag with Custom Key. I am unable to write it, I have tried with every option but unfortunately all the time I get the error "IOException: Transceive Failed".

Below is my code snippet:

```
byte custom_key[]={
  (byte)0xff,(byte)0xff,(byte)0xff,(byte)0xff,(byte)0xff,(byte)0xff
};

// 16 bytes of Data. Otherwise it was throwing IllegalArgumentException .
byte[] data="Hello world of N".getBytes();
getMfc().connect();

if(getMfc().authenticateSectorWithKeyA(4, custom_key)) {
  getMfc().writeBlock(3, data); // Here I receive IOException all the time.
} else {
  getMfc().close();
}
```

Please help me in this regard. I need to write Mifare Classic 1 K Tag with my own key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You authenticate to sector 4 and then you try to write to block 3. Block 3 is in sector 0, so this will always fail. Try authenticating to sector 0 instead.

**BTW:** Please, don't write random data to a sector trailer (such as block 3). It will likely lock up the sector with no way to recover.

Comment: Thank you for your reply NFC guy. But I am trying to write at Sector 4 in Block 3 . I just want to write my data with my own Key . so that no App can read that but only mine . It is still throwing error to me.

Comment: NFC guy was abolutely  right. I was thinking that each sector has block from 0 to 3 but infact block is zero indexed . So I am able to write it at sector 0 in block 2 and yes I need to change key also so I can write at Trailor block also with my own key . that way Mifare Classic 1 K card can be authenticated with custom key :) .

Comment: I want to write to a particular sector with a custom key. How can I read and write with a custom key ? @NFC guy ?

Comment: @Mani can you please check this and help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76925783/setting-custom-key-for-mifare-card-read-write-operations

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the question is how to edit block 3 in sector 4.
After authentication you try to write to block 3. But:
A blocks number does not start at 0 in every block. Sector 0 has blocks 0-3, sector 1 has blocks 4-7, and so on. Sector 4 has a block-offset of 4*4=16. So the block you want to write to is block 19.

There is a function available that calculates this offset for you. sectorToBlock(4) yields 16.
For writing to block 3 in sector 4 I would use the following:
getMfc().writeBlock(getMfc().sectorToBlock(4)+3, data)

The accepted answer does only provide the alternative that leaves the questioner unable to understand the block-indexing beyond sector 0.