# read block classic NFC

Tags: android, nfc

how to read data from sector 1?authenticate is true, I get exception with IOException("transceive failed").

```
private String readSector() {   
    byte [] array={(byte)0xD3,(byte)0xF7,(byte)0xD3,(byte)0xF7,(byte)0xD3,(byte)0xF7};
    byte[] data = null;
    final ByteArrayBuffer b = new ByteArrayBuffer(mMaxSize);
    String sb=new String();
    boolean succes = false;
    try {
        mClassic.connect();
        succes = mClassic.authenticateSectorWithKeyA(1, array);
        if (succes) {
            b.append(mClassic.readBlock(3), 1, 16);
            data = b.toByteArray();
        }
        else
             sb+="Authentication failed";
        mClassic.close();
    catch (final TagLostException tag) {
        tag.printStackTrace();
        sb+="Tag Lost";
    }
    catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        sb+="IOEception";
    }
}
```

Comment: This the same problem as question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154452/how-to-write-mifareclassic-with-custom-key

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154452/how-to-write-mifareclassic-with-custom-key not answer for me

Comment: You authenticate to sector 1 and then try to read block 3, which is in sector 0; exactly like in the other question.

Comment: sector 0 is Manufactor sector ,i have nfc encoder and write data on Tag classic ,i think data on sector 1,this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154452/how-to-write-mifareclassic-with-custom-key Question for write data,I want read data form classic tag,if Possible how find where story data ,please help me

Comment: Block 0 is the one that contains manufacturer data. It is in sector 0, but there are 3 more blocks in sector 0. Please, have a look at the [datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MF1S50YYX.pdf).

Comment: find it,sector 1 block 4,thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find it data on sector 1  block 4  to 6 ,and use this code for read data,

```
private String readMadSector() {
        byte [] array={(byte)0xD3,(byte)0xF7,(byte)0xD3,(byte)0xF7,(byte)0xD3,(byte)0xF7};
        byte[] data = null;
        byte [] b;
        String sb=new String();
    boolean succes = false;
    try {
                  mClassic.connect();
                succes = mClassic.authenticateSectorWithKeyA(1, array);
                                  b=mClassic.readBlock(4);

                  sb+=convertHex(b);


                  b=mClassic.readBlock(5);

                  sb+=convertHex(b);

                  b=mClassic.readBlock(6);

                  sb+=convertHex(b);
        else
              sb+="Authentication failed";

        mClassic.close();

    }

    catch (final TagLostException tag) {
        tag.printStackTrace();
        sb+="Tag Lost";
    }

    catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        sb+="IOEception";
    }





    return (sb.toString());
}
```